# problems about images after upgrade to UBUNTU 22.04 LTS (jammy)

Tags: upgrade, nautilus, thumbnails

After upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04 I experienced the following problems:

-No more thumbnails except old ones

-Nautilus doesn't show the "image properties" tap in the properties window

-Image viewer arrow navigation to next/previous image stopped working (arrow not there when multiple images in folder). Image viewer from flathub works as expected, but I cannot substitute the default one.

-Many Gimp icons were missing, I resolved installing it from flathub

My impression is that a part of the system doesn't recognize those files as images so that other applications do not access them as images, so if I am correct probably instead of a solution for each symptom it would be more correct to find a solution for this problem.

What can it be? What can I do to make it work as expected?

Comment: The reply from Rafa is a good start. Myself, I have never had success with upgrades, for exactly the problems you have. I learned the weeks spent trying to fix them was unnecessary. The quickest means to solve such problems is to perform a fresh install. My installs are usually about 25 minutes, then added time for options and installing add-ons. Usually done in 1 hour, and off to the races. Compared to the weeks of frustrations, 1 hr is a very quick, guaranteed solution. Of course, this is only an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this could be to remove .config, .local and .cache folders in your user home. The only issue is what by doing this you will be loossing any custom configuration.

Perhaps I would start removing .cache and if that doesnt work continue with other two.

This normally happens because ungrading ubuntus version temps to break configs due to version incompatibilitis

Comment: I renamed .cache and restarted, it didn't work but I discovered a  fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory folder into the user/ .cache/thumbnails folder  full of blank thumbs. That's a point.
Then I renamed the .local folder, restarted and it worked. So this is a correct answer.
I restored my previous not to lose all the other settings and kept the newly created to investigate the difference.

Comment: I moved one by one the folders in ~/.local/share/ since I've found that the problem was due to something with the ~/.local/share/mime folder. Without it everything works fine.
Then for the litte I can understand of the OS i tried to rebuild the mime types db by the command "update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime" but with no effect. I'm quite curious to understand what is the original problem but I've lost a lot of time so probably I'll just remove that folder and go on with doing what I have a computer for... thank you for your correct address

Comment: I couldn't resist to investigate more and the next level of detail is removing the mime.cache file. update-mime-database resets it to the not working state (as the other sibling files) so it doesn't look like the final answer. Maybe I should compare the XMLs in the usr/shared/mime folder with those ones in the user home to find the solution

Comment: I experienced the same after the upgrade to 22.04. Renamed .cache and .local, restarted. Then copied back the files into the newly created .local, without replacing the existing ones. Problem solved. Thanks.